# Python "try except" prevent from continuing on with normal code

Tags: python, try-except

Say I have the following code:

```
try:
    function a()
except someError:
    function b()

resume_code
```

is it possible so that if an error occurs, and function b is run, stay within function b, and don't continue with resume_code?

Comment: Put `resume_code` inside the `try` block…!?

Comment: What's wrong with putting the `resume_code` in the try block?

Comment: By _stay within function b_, do you mean, like, forever? Or just call it and proceed without executing `resume_code`?

Comment: You _will_ stay inside function b() … until it returns.  And then what?  You can `return` or `break` or whatever after calling function b() in the except clause.  But you will have to decide.

Comment: @bereal I'm trying to have it so that when it executes function b(), it won't then go back to resume_code, once function b is done with

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer using `try...else` in this case. That way, if `a()` succeeds, but `resume_code` fails, `b()` will not be called (I guess, that was the intention):

```
try:
    a()
except someError:
    b()
else:
    resume_code
```

Comment: Or simply add a `return` after the call of function `b()` in the `except` clause.  Then you don't have to shift the `resume_code` into an `else` clause.

Comment: @Alfe yep or that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use else.

```
    try:
        function a()
    except someError:
        function b()
    else:
        resume_code
```

Comment: Or simply add a `return` after the call of function `b()` in the `except` clause.  Then you don't have to shift the `resume_code` into an `else` clause.

Comment: @Alfe: Yes, if the `resume code` is the only code in the function needed to be skipped. Using `try..except..else` will be useful even if there is some `skip_to_this_line` which needs to run in case of exception.